# Trying to calculate a factorial e^x, x being what the user enters, having trouble with the formula

Tags: java

I am in a Java class and it's still early in the class. The assignment is to:
`e^x` Approximations

The value `ex` can be approximated by the following sum:
`1 + x + x^2/2! + x^3/3! + …+ x^n/n!`
The expression `n!` is called the factorial of `n` and is defined as: `n! = 1*2*3* …*n`.

Write a program that takes a value of `x` as input and outputs four approximations of `ex` done using four different values of `n`: `5`, `10`, `50`, and `100`. Output the value of `x` the user entered and the set of all four approximations into the screen.

Sample formula use: calculating e^7 using approximation with `n = 5
1 + 7 + 7^2/2! + 7^3/3! + 7^4/4! + 7^5/5!`

I've got all the rest to work, including getting `n` to be `5`, `10`, `50` and `100`. I thought I had the factorial formula figured out and I used the number 4 like the sample we were show and my numbers done match. Could really use another set of eyes.

Here's my code with forumla (`x` is the value the user enters and `n` is the `5`, `10`, `50` and `100`):

```
    /**
     * myFact takes in x and calculates the factorial
     * @param x
     * @param n
     * @return the factorial as a long
     */
    public static long myFact(int x, int n) {
        //declare variables
        long sum = x;

        for (int i=2; i <= n; i++) {
             sum += ((Math.pow(x, i))/i);
        }

        return (sum + 1);
    }
}
```

Here's the main class where I am calling the function. The error I suppose could be there too:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //declare variable for user input and call method to initialize it
    int x = getNumber();
    long fact;
    int n;
    //Output first line
    System.out.println("N\t approximate e^" + x);

    for (n = 5; n <= 100; n *= 2) {
        if (n == 10) {
            fact = myFact(x, n);
            System.out.println(n + "\t " + fact);
            n += 15;
       } else {
            fact = myFact(x, n);
            System.out.println(n + "\t " + fact);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for taking a look at this, it's taken me hours to get this as the teacher gave us very little help.

Answer (score 2):

You did a mistake in

```
sum += ((Math.pow(x, i))/i);
```

here you need to calculate the **i!**. Add below method in your code

```
public static int fact(int i){
    int fact = 1;
    for (int n = i; n > 0; n--) {
        fact = fact * n;
    }   
    return fact;
}
```

Also change sum += ((Math.pow(x, i))/i) to

```
sum += ((Math.pow(x, i))/fact(i));
```

Comment: Why does i need to be calculated? i is defined in the loop. Sum starts out as the number entered and when it's returned it has +1 added, so that takes care of the "1 + e " part of the formula. Then e needs to be squared which is why I started i at 2 and then for each loop it increases by 1 until it equals N, which is the 5,10, 50 or 100 number

Comment: @Lisa to calculate  x^3/3! you need to divide  x^3 by 3!. In your code where you are calculating.

Comment: I thought I had done it here:
sum += ((Math.pow(x, i))/i);

I may have done it wrong however, but I used Math.pow and then / it by i.